# aarch64 inline assembly stack pointer constraint memory address with offset for Clang 6+

Tags: stack, clang, inline-assembly, memory-address, arm64

I noticed at different optimization levels, Clang 6 is sometimes using ldp (load neon register pair) for adjacent memory addresses vld1 neon load instrinsics.

I am trying to use inline assembly to manually force more load pair instructions. The source array is held in the stack and when Clang itself produces ldp instructions, it is using a stack pointer with offset however when I enter the array with its index with inline assembly, it expands into a x register for the address. This works however is causing performance regression. I believe this is because reading from the stack is faster but a x register as a source address might be pointing to the heap which may in turn referencing back to the stack though I am not sure, or perhaps it is reading from duplicate data in the heap.
This is an example what I am using now.

```
asm (
    "ldp %q[DST1], %q[DST2], [%[SRC]]" "\n"
    : [DST1] "=w" (TMP1), [DST2] "=w" (TMP2)
    : [SRC] "X" (&K2[8])
);
```

and this is what Clang expands it into

```
ldp q19, q4, [x11]
```

But I want to use a stack pointer with offset address, automatically resolved from the indexed K2 array variable. e.g.

```
ldp q19, q4, [sp,#32]
```

The offsets of the stack pointer address in the disassembled code are not adjacent, so I cannot just hard code the sp register and enter an offset to load sequential data. This is because Clang 6 is consolidating identical values in other arrays used by other functions into the stack.

GCC has the aarch64 machine constraints like *k* which is for the stack pointer (sp) register and *Ump* which are meant for stp and ldp store/load pair instruction addresses which I never got to work on either GCC or Clang the latter having no equivalent constraints in its sparse documentation.

My preference is to use Clang 6 as it is producing code that is over 6% faster than GCC 8 because it is arranging most of the instructions in a performance critical loop to dual issue properly.

Is there anyway to enter an array with index as input into inline assembly and have it automatically resolve to a stack pointer with offset address in Clang 6?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a memory source operand like `[SRC] "m" (K2[8])`?  Without that, you haven't even told the compiler that the memory contents are also an input to the inline asm, so it might reorder your asm wrt. stores, or do dead-store elimination.

Letting the compiler pick the addressing mode is the entire point of `"m"` operands.